# Why when I submit the form of the jQuery UI dialog, it resfreshes the page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

```
$('#createGroupPopup > form').submit(function() {
    event.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "form.php?action=group_create",
        data: $('#createGroupPopup > form').serialize(),
        success: function() {
            event.preventDefault();
            $('#createGroupPopup').dialog("close");
        }
    });
})
```

Why when I submit the form of the jQuery UI dialog, it resfreshes the page whereas i've put the event.preventDefault() ?

Comment: Typo: `event` is not defined.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add `event` as an argument to the `function()`. Right now you're relying on the global event object which isn't available in all browsers.

```
$('#createGroupPopup > form').submit(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "form.php?action=group_create",
    data: $(this).serialize(),
    success: function() {
      $('#createGroupPopup').dialog("close");
    }
  });
});
```

Also note the use of `this` in the AJAX request to fill the data and the removal of `preventDefault()` in the callback as it's redundant at that point.

Answer (score -1):

Can u try this:

```
$('#createGroupPopup > form').submit(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "form.php?action=group_create",
        data: $('#createGroupPopup > form').serialize(),
        success: function(evt) {
            evt.preventDefault();
            $('#createGroupPopup').dialog("close");
        }
    });
})
```